# Special Currency Character

Tags: symbols, unicode, hebrew

I have the problem, that I need to insert the NIS (New Israeli Shekel) Symbol into a otherwise english document with math formulas. The Symbol itself is in testmode. How can I manage to get the symbol? It can be a hack as well...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! If you’re referring to the Unicode symbol ₪, you can simply use that symbol, compiling with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, together with `fontspec` and a font that supports this symbol, e.g. Arial or Times on a Windows machine.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers! Is there also a possibility while using pdftex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find a good version of the symbol on line or create it yourself by compiling with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX the file

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\begin{document}
\symbol{"20AA}
\end{document}
```

If you call the file `NIS.tex`, then you'll have `NIS.pdf`. Then, in your document, you can just say

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\NIS}{\includegraphics[height=\fontcharht\font`T]{NIS}}
```

and use the command normally:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\NIS}{\includegraphics[height=\fontcharht\font`T]{NIS}}

\begin{document}
I paid \NIS 200

\Large I paid \NIS 200
\end{document}
```

[image]

See [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files) for instructions about where to put `NIS.pdf` in order for it to be available for every document.

Answer (score 10):

It's easy to do with `fontspec` and an Opentype font that has that symbol; its code is `U+20AA`. This  requires compiling with `Xe/LuaLaTeX`. Here is an example with `DejaVu Sans`. I define a `\NIS` macro:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Heuristica}
\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}

\newcommand\NIS{\char"20AA\,}

\begin{document}
This is the New Schekel Symbol: \\

\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{@{}cccc}
\texttt{regular} & \texttt{bold} & \texttt{italic} & \texttt{bold italic}\\[2ex]
\NIS 2 & \bfseries \NIS & \itshape \NIS &\bfseries\itshape \NIS
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There should be a space: `\newcommand{\NIS}{\char"20AA }` or something like `\NIS 2` would give quite surprising results.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks! I must say I didn't think of checking. Updated answer.

Comment: Sorry, but the thin space is wrong. I meant a *space character*. Better yet, `\newcommand{\NIS}{\symbol{"20AA}}`

Comment: I put a thin space because it's the usual spacing between number and unit — at least in French typography. What does the use of `\symbol` do?

Comment: `\symbol` avoids the problem with numbers (no strange space after `"20AA`). Dollar and pound symbols don't want a thin space when preceding the amount; I dare say that most of the French typesetting rules are not followed in other languages.

Comment: I see. I must say I know only partially English rules (mainly British ones), better French rules , vaguely German ones and not at all the rest. Any way, I'll modify my answer. Thanks for the information about \symbol!